# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class is not found in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-security

I started learning about Spring Security today. All the tutorials are using `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in their Security Configuration. When I try to do the same I am getting the following error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
  location: package org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bilolbek</groupId>
    <artifactId>checkSecurity</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>checkSecurity</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is the configuration java class, which is empty:

```
package com.bilolbek.checkSecurity;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
}
```

> I found this info on the official website:
> In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 we deprecated the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, as we encourage users to move towards a component-based security configuration.

How can I make my Spring Security work in this case?

I tried to add this dependency as well:

```
<dependency>
    <groupid>org.springframework.security</groupid>
    <artifactid>spring-security-config</artifactid>
    <version>4.1.3.release</version>
</dependency>
```

Did not work

Comment: Find an up-to-date tutorial **or** stick to the versions used in the tutorial instead of moving to the newest versions. Don't add some old ancient version to something that is build for Spring Security 6 it will only make things worse, never mix jars from different versions of a framework, that is trouble waiting to happen!.

Answer (score 1):

Spring security 6 has removed WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

You need to use the new method to configure the security filter chain as follows

```
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
```